# AOT compilation with ngtools/webpack, compiler still present in bundle

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to use AOT compilation to produce production build. Everything seems to be working nicely, except I still have `compiler` in vendor bundle. AFAIK one of goals of AOT compilation is to remove it from resulting bundle and to reduce app size.

How can I produce proper AOT build without `compiler` in resulting bundle?

My webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var ngtools = require('@ngtools/webpack');
var AotPlugin = ngtools.AotPlugin;

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'source-map',

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('../../../target/rhamt-web'),
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        chunkFilename: 'js/[id].chunk.js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /jquery*\.js/,
                loaders: '@ngtools/webpack'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].css'),
        new AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: './tsconfig-production.json',
            basePath: '.',
            mainPath: 'src/main.ts',
            skipCodeGeneration: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
            mangle: {
                keep_fnames: true
            }
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "inlineSources": false,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "../../../target/tscoutput"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  }
}
```

I have these version of tools:

```
angular: 4.1.2 
@ngtools/webpack: 1.3.1 
webpack: 2.2.0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136701/optimize-angular-vendor-output

Comment: Thanks for reference, unfortunately it didn't help :(

Comment: Same problem here.
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic is only referenced from boot file that should be rewritten on the fly by ngtools.

Comment: Try changing `skipCodeGeneration:true` to `false`